# SocketException 16010 on GET/POST to https from local WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, https, socketexception

I have a local C# WCF service I am writing.  I have it working fine, except for the place where it needs to interact with a https api.  I get a socketexception (16010) whenever I try to get/post to https (works fine with http calls)

Example:

```
    private async void test()
    {
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        //The next line works just fine, I get a response back
        var r = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en");
        HttpContent responseContent = r.Content;

        //SOCKETEXCEPTION 16010 at next line
        var r2 = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en");           
        HttpContent responseContent2 = r2.Content;
    }
```

This happens when I have my service running through visual studio debugger (iis express) and also when I host it on my local full IIS server with an application pool running on my credentials.

I am not sure how to even start chasing this one.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Exception Details:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred
Message: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Using the ServiceStack

```
             var a = "https://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en".GetXmlFromUrl();
```

I'm getting the following:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred
  _HResult=-2147467259
  _message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsTransient=false
  Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 23.21.209.160:443
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=10060
  NativeErrorCode=10060
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this problem? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You sure your first call isn't is disposing or changing the state of the `client` object?  Have you tried this?

```
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

    //The next line works just fine, I get a response back
    var r = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en");
    HttpContent responseContent = r.Content;

    //SOCKETEXCEPTION 16010 at next line
    client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    var r2 = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en");           
    HttpContent responseContent2 = r2.Content;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the https call fails even if it's all by itself

Comment: you sure that https is available?

Comment: I am able to navigate with my browser to that https call, on same machine that the iis is running and with same account in the application pool for my wcf service.